# How can 'this' be undefined when my method is called [Typescript]?

Tags: typescript

I see a javascript console error: 'cannot call method '_getSubscriptionsHeader' of undefined CachingArea.ts:98'. _fetchData is a method on the CachingData class.

```
_fetchData(dataSetName: string, uri: string, ajaxData: any, ajaxHeaders: any) { ... }
```

Why would `this` be undefined when the member is invoked?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/typescript+this?sort=votes

Comment: See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tvocUcbCupA&hd=1